# Цикл for и его секреты, если они есть?

Tags: java

Хотелось бы узнать как будет выполняться цикл for:
1) Вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Цикл for будет выполняться по 1 варианту.

Comment: А почему я допустим беру пример for(int a = 1; a < 5; a++) и здесь я прохожусь как по второму варианту и все хорошо отрабатывает

Comment: Я почему-то везде читаю, но пошагово не нашел

Comment: а с каких пор в java for пишет с заглавной буквы?

Comment: @KoVadim да это я в painte не заметил,  а так с маленькой

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во всех сиподобных языках цикл `for` будет выполняться вот так:

[image: скриншот с номерами]

Или в виде гифки

[image: скринвидео с отладчика]

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85404/discussion-between-qwertiy-and--).

Answer (score 5):

Зачем гадать, когда есть [документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

```
for (initialization; termination; increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:

The **initialization** expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, **as the loop begins**.

When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.

The **increment** expression is invoked **after each iteration** through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment or decrement a value.

Последняя фраза говорит о том, что

Инкремент (или другое изменение) счётчика выполняется после тела цикла.

Так что пример из вопроса эквивалентен следующему коду:

```
   a = 1
@@start
   if (a < 5)
    {
       print(i);
    };
   i++;
   goto @@start
```

Comment: Если честно прочитал с переводом и не понял, где в документации показывается первый вариант(

Comment: Инкремент (или другое изменение) счётчика выполняется после тела цикла

Comment: А почему он не может пройтись так сказать слева направо, вывести в саут, а потом со след раза добавить i значение 1

Comment: Кто может или не может? Компилятор (или JIT) генерирует код согласно спецификации.